# Convert Javascript string to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code of a table in a javascript string, when I convert this code to html object,
some html tag disappared and remain only the content of itss tag...
this is my code

```
var tab = this.model.get("table");
console.log(tab);                   //here the result is exactly
$(tab).appendTo(this.el)            //here some tags were hidden
```

http://pastebin.com/UWpuM6vh Here is the exactly result;

http://pastebin.com/gcSNFg1a And here is the results with htdden tags.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. excuse me for my bad english... :)

Comment: could you make a JSFiddle of this issue?

Comment: What is `this.el` actually represent? Is it a `<table>` tag?

Comment: No problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/NJdak/

Comment: I really really hate the dashes in the comments. Really.